# Adding a list the class

Tags: python

```
class Course:
    ''' 
    A class representing a course offering that includes the following
    information about the course: subject, course number, section,
    enrolment cap, lecture days, lecture start time, lecture duration 
    in minutes, and unique student numbers of the students enroled.
    If lectures occur on multiple days, they will all start at the same time.
    '''

    def __init__(self, subject, number, section, cap, days, start_time, dur):
        '''
        returns a new Course object with no students enroled, given
           the subject, number, section, cap, days, start_time, and dur
        __init__: Str Nat Nat Nat Str Time Nat -> Course
        requires: number is a 3-digit number, section > 0, cap > 0,
           days is string containing substrings representing the days
           of the week 'M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', where if the course is
           offered on more than one day, the days appear in order and
           are separated by a single dash. For example, 'M-T-Th'
           indicates the course is offered on Monday, Tuesday, and Th.
        '''
        self.subject = subject
        self.number = number
        self.section = section
        self.cap = cap
        self.days = days
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.dur = dur

    def add_student(self, student_id):
        '''
        adds a student to the course enrolment if there is room in the course
           if the number of students enroled already matches the 
           enrolment cap, then print the message "Course full"
           if the student is already enroled in the course, the there is no 
           change to the Course object, and the message "Previously enroled"
           is printed.
        add_student: Course Nat -> None
        Effects: Mutates self. May print feedback message.
        '''
        pass
```

For the method add_student, how would i implement a list if it not in the **init** method, (CANT ADD IT TO THE INIT METHOD)? The list need to be connected with the object so later on i can remove students from that list.

Comment: Why can't you add a list in the `__init__` method?

Comment: Its a requirement for the question.

Comment: @Michael That's a totally stupid requirement that forces the student to go against good practices. You can go tell your teacher that no serious professional developper would do that, and that such code wouldn't pass a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

naive method: try if the member exists, catch the attribute error, and create it if doesn't exist.

```
def add_student(self, student_id):
    try:
        self.__list
    except AttributeError:
        self.__list = []
    self.__list.append(student_id)
```

better use a "getter" instead to make sure the list is created when you access it from whatever method:

```
def get_list(self):
    try:
        self.__list
    except AttributeError:
        self.__list = []
   return self.__list
```

then `add_student` becomes:

```
def add_student(self, student_id):
    self.get_list().append(student_id)
```

of course adding it to `__init__` is better if you don't have some strange constraints...

Comment: This is not a good answer because there's no guarantee that the `add_student` method is always called before the list is accessed by some other methods.

Comment: Yes it's better, although having all other methods call this method is not going to be very pretty. Not going to upvote this but I've removed my downvote. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @blhsing np, it's not worth many upvotes in the first place because it's not wise _not_ to initialize the variable in `__init__`. Stupid homework requirements...

Comment: Absolutely. Quite a silly requirement to begin with. Still a somewhat interesting exercise in finding workarounds though.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it in the `__new__` method instead:

```
class Course:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        course = super(Course, cls).__new__(cls)
        course.students = []
        return course
```

Comment: Arf ! very creative work-around for a totally silly requirement !-)

Comment: now the teacher knows the student is cheating. But yeah. Only sound alternative. Or was it what the teacher wanted? far-fetched.

Comment: @Aran-Fey True. Edited as suggested then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the list with a [property getter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property), so that it would be initialized whenever it is first accessed:

```
class Course:
    @property
    def students(self):
        try:
            return self._students
        except AttributeError:
            self._students = []
            return self._students

    @students.setter
    def students(self, value):
        self._students = value
```

Comment: The setter is useless and (imho) even harmful here.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you make `_students` an implementation ("protected") attribute - which is what the single leading underscode means, and which is the right thing to do here (the client code has no business knowing how students are "stored" in the Course objects - this might as well use a database of any kind, or a dict, or a set, or whatever...), then you don't want to allow client code to overwrite `_students`.

Comment: That's what I thought you'd say, but seeing how the OP has all the other attributes named without a leading underscore I'm just here trying to make `students` as available as the other attributes. Also, if I didn't have a setter, then other methods would need to set `_students` directly, which may not have been initialized. This prevents other methods from using list comprehension to implement operations such as removing students matching certain condition from the course, and can only modify the list in-place, which may not be ideal because lists are inefficient at in-place removal.

Comment: "Also, if I didn't have a setter, then other methods would need to set _students directly" => how would it be a problem ? That's ok for a method to directly access implementation attributes of it's own class/instance. But anyway: the base problem is, of course, the totally inept requirement to not creates `self._students` in the initializer.

Comment: But the problem as I mentioned is that a method would not be able to access `_student` if it isn't initialized by the getter first, which means all methods are limited to a logical workflow that uses the getter before the setter, so the point of a setter here is for the methods to be able to set `_student` without the need to use the getter first.

Comment: Then the solution might be to name the implementation attribute otherwise and rename the property as `_students` so it becomes an implementation detail too. And __eventually__ to provide a public read-only property - if that's part of the spec, of course.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd name it if the OP didn't name all the other attributes without an underscore. Anyway I think we've at least agreed on the need for a setter for methods in this silly case. :-)